# dompdf and 3 column holy grail dont work (columns side by side)

Tags: css, cakephp, dompdf

How to have dompdf use the 3 column holy grail layout?

I need my pdf with 3 vertical columns. for html page is fine, problem when done via dompdf.

I've fiddled  with /dompdf/lib/res/html.css and added the 3-column styles.

pdf file does reflect the css changes -color, footers, etc. on html.css file but fails to accomodate col1,col2and col3 side by side.

```
<div class="colmask threecol">
<div class="colmid">
    <div class="colleft">
        <div class="col1">
            <p>Inside col1</p>
        </div>       
        <div class="col2">
            <p>Inside col2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <p>Inside col3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Probably dompdf is overriding my div classes. I found out html.css is used as default so i'm cutomizing it, I'd also like to find a better way to give my styles to dompdf?

Can you help?

Thank you so much.

(the css adjusted to 70 percent and different widths)

```
.colmask {
position:relative;  /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug */
clear:both;
float:left;
width:70%;          /* width of whole page */
overflow:hidden;        /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
}
/* common column settings */
.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {
float:left;
width:100%;         /* width of page */
position:relative;
}
.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
float:left;
position:relative;
padding:0 0 1em 0;  /* no left and right padding on columns, we just make them narrower instead 
                only padding top and bottom is included here, make it whatever value you need */
overflow:hidden;
}

.col1 {
border-bottom:1px solid #fbd850; 
}
.col2 {
border-bottom:1px solid #ee5f5b;
}
.col3 {
border-bottom: 1px solid #00c;
}

/* 3 Column settings */
.threecol {
background:#eee;        /* right column background colour */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.threecol .colmid {
right:25%;          /* width of the right column */
background:#fff;        /* center column background colour */
}
.threecol .colleft {
right:50%;          /* width of the middle column */
background:#f4f4f4; /* left column background colour */
}
 .col1 {
width:20%;          /* width of center column content (column width minus padding on either side) */
            /* 100% plus left padding of center column */
}
.col2 {
width:25%;          /* Width of left column content (column width minus padding on either side) */
left:24%;           /* width of (right column) plus (center column left and right padding) plus (left column left padding) */
}
.col3 {
width:20%;          /* Width of right column content (column width minus padding on either side) */
left:80%;           /* Please make note of the brackets here:
                (100% - left column width) plus (center column left and right padding) plus (left column left and right padding) plus (right column left padding) */
}
```

Comment: Is your sample code incomplete? I'm not seeing anything from col1 or col3 (even in a web browser).

Comment: As far as how to feed the CSS to dompdf, link to the CSS or place it in the document header as you would for any web browser.